# How can I get also 0 sum when month data not exist

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-4.x

I am trying below query to get group by sum data for coins , I am using postgres.

```
$query
    ->select([
        'month' => "DATE_PART('month', date)",
        'total_sum_coin' => $query->func()->sum('SummaryCoins.get_count')
    ])
    ->where([
         'SummaryCoins.date >='=> '2020-12-01',
         'SummaryCoins.date <='=> '2021-05-01',
    ])
    ->group([
        'month'
    ])
    ->order([
        'month' => 'ASC'
    ])
;
```

Output that I'm getting

```
3   22
4   77
5   34
```

My desire output is

```
12     0
2      0
3      22
4      77
5      34
```

How can I get sum 0, when data is not exist in any month ?

## Update

I can write this query to get my desire data , but unable to implement in cakephp query builder.

```
SELECT DATE_PART('month', x) AS month, COALESCE(TOTAL, 0) AS total
        FROM generate_series(
            date_trunc('month', date'2020-10-01'),
            date_trunc('month', date'2021-4-01'),
            interval'1 month') AS x(x)
        LEFT JOIN LATERAL (
        SELECT SUM(GET_COUNT) AS TOTAL
            FROM SUMMARY_COINS
        WHERE date_trunc('month', date) = x
            AND user_id = 1
        ) AS s ON TRUE
        ORDER BY x;
```

Comment: Read more: https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#working-with-result-sets

Comment: @Salines I have written postgres query where I am able to get my desire result in query end but problem is unable to implement it query builder ! I have updated my question.